# Set caption for dropdown list

Tags: c#, jquery, css, asp.net, html-select

I have a dropdownlist on a page for which I want to set a text so that whether or not user makes any selection, it should always be displayed to the user and not the selected value.

For example:

[image]

Here `Select Language` should always be visible to user even if I select any value from the list i.e. `Option 1` or `Option 2`.

I guess it is more of a CSS task which I am not very much comfortable with.

Comment: Why would you want this? It's completely non standard and will most likely confuse users as it will look like they have not yet made a selection, when they in fact have. To do this would involve a lot more than CSS alone. I would strongly suggest you instead use `label` elements next to the `select` which are always visible, so the user always knows the context of the option which has been chosen.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about a simple **asp:DropDownList**, you just need to insert an item in it, with an index value of 0 (to deal with server-side checks).

```
myDropDownList.Items.Insert(0, "Select");
```

Comment: This isn't what the user was asking - they want the first option to remain visible even when a selection has been made.

Comment: My bad. I didn't read it that way, as it it makes your point about this being non-standard true.

Answer (score 0):

```
dropdownlist1.Text="SomeText";
```

Dropdownlist need to have  the data-source.

Answer (score 0):

> Here Select Language should always be visible to user even if I select
>   any value from the list i.e. Option 1 or Option 2.

Solution:

1. if your dropdownlist isn't autopost back enabled then

Maintain a hidden field where on change event of the dropdownlist place the selected value or selected index or selected text there in the hidden field to remember the selection.

lets says the id of your dropdownlist is **sel** and hidden field is **hdSel**, the jquery code for that look likes below

```
$('#sel').change(function(){
    var val = $("#sel option:selected").text();
    $('#hdSel').val(val);
    $("#sel").prop('selectedIndex', 0);
    }
);
```

[example on Jsfiddle for your understanding](https://jsfiddle.net/TanzeelurRehman/6f9pp9e7/2/)

2. If your dropdownlist is autopostback enable then you can assign the selected value or selected text or selected index of the dropdownlist to the hidden field and reselect the first item again

Hope this help